# How to delete a certain model instance in django after a given date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
class Mess(models.Model):
     muser = models.OneToOneField(User)
     MESS_NAME = (('GH','girls hostel top mess'),
                ('IH','girls hostel down mess'),
                ('MM','Mega mess'),
                ('FB','First Block mess'),
                ('SB','Second Block mess'),
                ('TB','Third Block mess'),
                )
     mess_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices =MESS_NAME,primary_key=True)
     per_day_cost = models.IntegerField()
     def __str__(self):
    return self.mess_name

class MessMenu(models.Model):
    mess_name = models.ForeignKey(Mess)
    day = models.DateField()
    morning = models.TextField()
    afternoon = models.TextField()
    snacks = models.TextField()
    dinner = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mess_name
```

Once i create an object in MessMenu I want django to delete that object after 7 days. Please let me know how to delete a certain object after a given period of time.

Comment: You need to write the code that checks what is 7 days old and then delete them... then you need to make a way to call that code.

Comment: can you elaborate @Sayse

Answer (score 0):

Add a creation_date to your model.

If this model belongs to a user: check if any models are outdated when the user logs in.

Otherwise you write a method which you always call before you access the model. It returns True if you can access the model and False, if it's outdated. If it returns False you delete it.

Or you write a watchdog.

Answer (score 0):

```
menudeleted = MessMenu.objects.filter( day__lt = timezone.now())
    for m in menudeleted:
        m.delete()
menu = MessMenu.objects.all()
```

[use basic comparison filter](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BasicComparisonFilters) to filter the dates